# How to Pull Nested Arrays using React and MongoDB?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

My Backend is perfectly fine because my aim is to remove inside of an array. On my FrontEnd is not  working(unable to remove logActivities._id). How can I remove in a nested array of object using react-hooks?

- In BackEnd: By sending a PUT request, Im type a logs/(URL logActivities._id) then after Im type inside the logActivities._id using JSON
- In FrontEnd: In a list, Im able to click a remove button and nothing happens because my aim to press a button then in a next page (Im using useNavigate to navigate to another page including the state(logAct) and pluck logActivities._id as a body or submitting a form). By the time of pressed(Remove a button to pull a nested array of objects[*pushing a nested arrray is fined cause using logs._id]) and it works but the database nothing happens....

```
// logController.js

const removeLog = asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {
  const inputLogActivities = req.body._id
  console.log(inputLogActivities)

  Log.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, 
  {
    $pull: {
      logActivities: {
        _id: {
          $in: [inputLogActivities]  // DELETE using _id
        }
      }
    }
  }).then(
    () => {
      res.status(200).send({
        success: true, 
        msg: 'Log has been removed'
      })
    }
  ).catch(
    (error) => {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: error
      })
    }  
  )
})
```

[image: Remove logActivities._id which inside logs]

#### Here is my code for my FrontEnd

```
// logSlice.jsx

const initialState = {
  // logs: {
  //   logActivities:[]
  // },
  logs: [],
  isError: false, 
  isSuccess: false, 
  isLoading: false
}


export const logSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'logs',
  initialState, 
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = false
      state.isSuccess = false
      state.isError = false
    }
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
     // THIS PART
    .addCase(removeLog.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false
      state.isSuccess = true
      state.logs = state.logs.filter(
        (log) => log._id !== action.payload.id
      )
    })
  }
})
```

```
// RIGHT
const removeLog = async (removeData, token) => {

  try {
    
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    }

    const logsID = removeData.id //logs params
    const removeLogData = removeData.removeLogss // when submitting the form


    const res = await axios.put(API_URLLOGS + `/removeLog/${logsID}`, removeLogData, config)

    // console.log(res.data)

    switch (res.status) {
      case 200:
        toast.success(res.data.msg, {
          theme: 'dark',
          position: 'top-right',
          autoClose: 3000,
          hideProgressBar: false,
          closeOnClick: true,
          draggable: false,
          progress: undefined
        })
        // setTimeout(function(){ window.location = '/logs' }, 4000);        
        break;
      default:
        return res.data
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }

}
```

```
// confirmRemoveLog.jsx
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

import Navbar from '../../../layouts/Navbar'

import { removeLog } from '../../../features/logs/logSlice'

import { useParams, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'


function confirmRemoveLog() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const logID = useParams() // getting params (URL logID)
  // console.log(logID.id)

  const location = useLocation()
  const data = location.state // getting state (logAct to pluck _id[logActivities])
  const { _id } = data // logActID


  const initialRemoveLogState = {
    id: _id // get id as input
  }

  const [removeLogss, setRemoveLogss] = useState(initialRemoveLogState)

  const handleInputChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    setRemoveLogss({ ...removeLogss, [name]: value})
  }

  // Submit to remove logActivities._id
  const onSubmit = e => {

    e.preventDefault()

    dispatch(removeLog(
      {id:logID.id,
      removeLogss}))
    .then(data => {
      setRemoveLogss({
        id: data.meta.arg.removeLogss.id, 
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    }) 
  }

  return(
    <>
      <Navbar />
      {/* FORM for Removed Log*/}
      <section className="addLog mt-5">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="card text-center">
              <div className="card-header h4">
                <i className="bi bi-exclamation-circle me-3"></i> Removed Logs
              </div>
              <div className="card-body">
                <p className="text-center text-black">Do you want delete this log? {_id}</p>

                <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                  <input 
                    type="hidden" 
                    name="id" // id as input
                    value={ removeLogss.id || ''} // id as input  
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                  />
                  <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-altdanger ms-3">
                      <i className="bi bi-trash3-fill me-2"></i> Remove Logs
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
    </>
  )
}

export default confirmRemoveLog
```

Here is my Image on Doing it

[image: Submit to Remove(logActivities._id)]

Answer (score 1):

The `removeLog` action is passed an undefined `token` argument.

```js
dispatch(removeLog({ id: logID.id, removeLogss })) // <-- no token passed
```

```js
const removeLog = async (removeData, token) => { ... } // <-- token undefined
```

Also, from what I can understand of your code it would appear that you are expecting your `removeLog` function to generate/create/etc a `fulfilled` action for the `extraReducers` of the `logSlice` to process. For this though `removeLog` would need to be a Redux-Toolkit `createAsyncThunk` action and not just some regular asynchronous function.

```js
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
...

const toastConfig = {
  theme: 'dark',
  position: 'top-right',
  autoClose: 3000,
  hideProgressBar: false,
  closeOnClick: true,
  draggable: false,
  progress: undefined
};

const removeLog = createAsyncThunk(
  "logs/removeLog",
  async ({ id, removeLogss, token }, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      }

      const { data } = await axios.put(
        API_URLLOGS + `/removeLog/${id}`,
        removeLogss,
        config
      );

      if (res.status === 200) {
        toast.success(data.msg, toastConfig);
      }

      return { id }; // <-- return id to remove
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  },
);
```

`createAsyncThunk` generates the `.pending`, `.fulfilled`, and `.rejected` actions.

```js
.addCase(removeLog.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  state.isLoading = false;
  state.isSuccess = true;
  state.logs = state.logs.filter(
    (log) => log._id !== action.payload.id // <-- used passed id
  );
})
```

The UI should dispatch the `removeLog` action, passing the `id` and `removeLogss` as properties on the payload parameter, and unwrap the result to know if the action was successful or not.

```js
// Submit to remove logActivities._id
const onSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault()

  dispatch(removeLog({
    id: logID.id,
    removeLogss,
    token, // <-- pass token, whatever it is
  }))
    .unwrap() // <-- unwrap resolved success or thrown rejection
    .then(data => {
      setRemoveLogss({
        id: data.meta.arg.removeLogss.id, 
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    });
};
```

Comment: But I want to removed the nested array of object using react and redux-toolkit. 
My BackEnd is perfectly fine

Comment: @Borgs Isn't this what the `removeLog.fulfilled` reducer does when it filters the `state.logs` value, e.g. `state.logs = state.logs.filter(log => log._id !== action.payload.id)`? Perhaps your `"/removeLog/:id"` endpoint doesn't return the `id` value that was removed. Is this the case? Can you check and report what the value of `data` is in your `removeLog` Thunk action? Maybe you just toast status 200 responses and `return id`, the `id` value that was passed to the action.

Comment: My aim is to remove a nested ARray by using id as a PAYLOAD and not logActivities._id 

Which is I do in BackEnd?

Wait Can I ask 
Can I add initialState [for nested array]?

Comment: @Borgs I see, then I think simply returning the `id` value from the Thunk should suffice, the reducer gets it from the payload. I'll update answer. Do you mean initially populate the `initialState.logs` array with a value/values? Yes, you can use whatever initial state value you want/need for the app state.

Comment: Do you update answer? for that

Comment: @Borgs I updated the answer to return the log id from the `removeLog` action so the reducer could properly filter the `state.logs` array. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Yes. But I want figure it out on another day maybe my payload is undefined

Comment: @Borgs Ok, I'm always around. Ping me again here in another comment when you are ready to pick this back up. If the option to start a chat is suggested then please use that.

Comment: Im figure it out this morning. I dont need the logs: {  logActivities: [] }. Just simply logs:[] and the removeLog.fulfilled. I dont have to  state.logs.logActivities anymore. Just simply state.logs.filter and filter the logs._id and the payload on its inside the nested array( logs.logActivities._id   )

Comment: @Borgs I see. Was the initial question/problem about filtering the `state.logs` array sufficiently addressed/resolved here in the answer?

Comment: yes because according to the BackEnd the params is logs._id and the payload is logActivities._id